# Conditions for extending a restricted vector bundle of an embedded submanifold to the whole manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $(\pi,E,M)$ is a vector bundle (total space $E$, base space $M$) and that $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold. If $E$ has positive rank, show that every smooth section of $E|_S$ (the vector bundle restricted to $S$) extends smoothly to all of $M$ $\iff$ $S$ is properly embedded.

So I'm trying to work this out and I'm not having much luck getting started. How is the fact that the embedding is proper going to help me out? Thanks

Comment: $S$ properly embedded exactly when $S$ is closed. Extend $E$ around neighbourhood of $S$ using partition of unity and then you can extend to the whole $M$ if $S$ is closed.

Comment: Hm, a parition of unity can be used to extend the vector field? How does $S$ being closed help exactly?

Comment: If you have $E$ around a neihghbourhood $U$ of $S$, you can extend it to $M$ by multiplting it by a bump function supported in $U$.

Comment: If S was open why couldn’t we surround it by a bigger open set U and do the same thing??

Comment: Generally we cannot extend function defined on open set. E.g. tan x on $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$.

Comment: Ahhh and we can on closed sets because of the Tietze extension theorem?? So that theorem is useful after all, haha. I was trying to think of some intuitive reason why you can only extend functions on closed sets, but maybe there isn't one, and rather you have to rely on this deep result.